# s3 file downloads are unpredictable

Tags: amazon-s3, download

We have uploaded several zip files to s3. All are in the hundreds of MB range.

We download the files, typically via a script, it appears that the file size and type both change.  The new file size typically is about 300 bytes and the file type once downloaded is xml.

The content of the files look similar to this (whitespace added for clarity):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error>      
  <Code>NoSuchKey</Code>
  <Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message>
  <Key>gpdb-5.0.0.0/greenplum-db-5.0.0.0-rhel5-x86_64.zip</Key>
  <RequestId>83D2047BDBA195A6</RequestId>    
  <HostId>tXKFaiRaNjD26j6fcrTjCk858PGBH2RAjLE1aO4+8hovD6mf+hUzJvCdWKKgrDJGaHXsjWbQP2A=</HostId>
</Error>
```

Any thoughts as to what might be causing this? It does not happen all of the time. It's somewhat intermittent.

Comment: How are you downloading the files?

Answer (score 0):

As you will note in the [S3 API Reference](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/ErrorResponses.html), this isn't a file -- it's an error message.

Files in S3 are called Objects, and the path + filename of the object is referred to as the object key.

> A key is the unique identifier for an object within a bucket. Every object in a bucket has exactly one key. [...] Every object in Amazon S3 can be uniquely addressed through the combination of the web service endpoint, bucket name, key, and optionally, a version. For example, in the URL `http://doc.s3.amazonaws.com/2006-03-01/AmazonS3.wsdl`, "`doc`" is the name of the bucket and "`2006-03-01/AmazonS3.wsdl`" is the key.
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Introduction.html#BasicsKeys

This error message, which should have been accompanied by a `404 Not Found` error code when you tried to access the object, indicates that there is no object in the bucket whose key (path + filename) is the one shown in the error -- the one you requested.  You should be able to confirm its absence in the S3 console.

If the object should have been uploaded some time in the past, this error means the object wasn't actually uploaded, or has subsequently been deleted.

If the object was *very* recently uploaded (typically within seconds), you should not get this error, but it is possible for this error to occur under either of two additional conditions:

- If you try to check whether an object exists by sending a `GET` or `HEAD` request to the bucket, then uploaded the object.  If you do this, a short period of time may elapse before the object is accessible because of internal optimizations inside S3.  When you try to fetch a non-existent object, S3 may -- for a brief time -- have an internal concept that the object is not there, even though it has safely been stored.  Retry your request.
- If you already had an object with the same key, then you deleted it, then you uploaded a new object with the same key, for a brief time after the new upload, you could either get the error above or you could actually download the old object again.

These conditions are somewhat uncommon, but they can occur, particularly if your bucket has a lot of traffic, due to S3's [consistency model](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Introduction.html#ConsistencyModel), which is an engineered tradeoff between performance, reliability, and immediate availability of uploaded objects when the same object has been recently downloaded, attempted to be downloaded, deleted, or overwritten.

The `<RequestId>` and `<HostId>` codes in the error response are opaque diagnostic codes that you can provide to AWS support, if you need to submit a support request about a specific problem you are experiencing with S3... they can use these to find the specific request and identify the problem.  They are not considered sensitive information, since they have no meaning outside of AWS.

In this case, there is no apparent need to contact AWS support, because it appears that you are simply trying to download an object that is not in the specific bucket from which you tried to download this particular file.  If you get alternating success and failure for the exact same file, that's unexpected, and a support case might be in order... but typically, an internal error in S3 should result in a very different response.